# SELENIUM IDE-Force script to move on if failed for example on clicking on an object

Tags: selenium-ide

If a script fails in IDE, say a click event as the object cannot be found , how can you get selenium to just move to the nex

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there got any way if the CLICK event is fail and let you continue for the subsequent event. (I would like to know as well if got :P )

Suggestion:
Plan you test cases with different scripts/test cases, example u have page A, inside page A have several buttons that you would like to run the test. Record each event of the button in several different selenium test cases, and run the test as in entire test suite mode. So that selenium will move to the next test cases when failed.

Hopes this help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need flowcontrol for Selenium IDE to do it

```
storeElementPresent | id=yourbutton   | found
gotoIf              | ${found}==false | NOTFOUND
click               | id=yourbutton
label               | NOTFOUND
```

The first command will store true or false about element presence.
The second will send script to the label NOTFOUND instead of making click in case if there is no button on your page.